# Norm of a complex cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ be a complex vector. How can we see that $\|c\|^2=\|c\times \bar{c}\|$? Here the bar means component wise complex conjugation, the norm is the Hermitian norm, and the cross product is defined by Sarrus's rule (as far as I can tell). Would the equality be true if we use another norm?

If you need, assume that $c_i$ are holomorphic functions on a Riemann surface, satisfying the cyclicity condition. Then $x(z) = \Re\int_p^z c \, dz$ is a conformal minimal immersion, for any $p \in S$. Moreover, $x_u \times x_v = \frac{1}{2} c \times \bar{c}$. Since $x$ is conformal,  $\|x_u \times x_v\| = \|x_u\|\cdot \|x_v\|$. I calculate $\|x_u \times x_v\|$ in many ways, but I fail to see that $\|x_u \times x_v\| = \frac{1}{2} \|c\|^2$. Obviously, $\|c\|^2 = \|x_u\|^2 + \|x_v\|^2 \not = 2 \|x_u\| \cdot \|x_v\|$.

The problem stems from the last formula in [these notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/lecture-notes/chapter18.pdf).

Comment: do you mean $|c\cdot \bar{c}|$? instead of $\Vert c\times \bar{c}\Vert$?

Comment: No, I do not. My motivation is in the second paragraph of the question and we can easily that $x_u\times x_v=\frac{1}{2} c\times\bar{c}$. To calculate the Gauss map, we need to normalize this vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is off here. Suppose  for simplicity that all components of  $c$ are real. If $c\times c$ is indeed a cross-product, then $\|c\times c\|=0\ne \|c\|^2$.

Comment: Yes, I knew. I am working our some notes I found on the internet. The above problem comes from the bottom of page 129, [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/lecture-notes/chapter18.pdf).

Comment: @Student so, basically, the problem reduces to "if $c\in \Bbb C^3$ is isothermal, then $|c\times c|= |c |^2$" (or, if we are to believe that article, that  $ Re(c\times c)=0$). Now all we need is the definition of being isothermal.

Comment: Isothermal is the same as conformal. Let $W$ be a Riemann surface. The map $x:W\to \mathbb R^n$ is isothermal exactly when $||x_u||=||x_v||$, and $\langle x_u,x_v\rangle$, where $\partial u,\partial v$ are linearly independent local sections of the tangent bundle of $W$. This is equivalent with $x$ preserving angles between curves.